# Problems implementing a Timline Editor in my level editor in Adobe AIR.

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I'm currently working on an Adobe AIR project to pump out my level editor but I'm running into an issue. I basically need to implement an interactive movie editor. My question is how would you recommend I get the timeline editing started? Functionality wise it needs to be able to set tween key frames for position, scale, and alpha. Any ideas?

I've also been trying to look into pulling tween data from a swf. I'm not entirely sure how applicable this would be.

Comment: You're in for a lot of work if you're planning on re-creating Flash within Flash.

Comment: Haha yes, I'm fighting with Flash... to make Flash... in Flash... to export a game for Flash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by movie editor - movie as in a sequence of images(bitmaps) or movie as in flash MovieClip ?

If it's the later, you could use a tweening engine like TweenLite to do the hard lifting and then it's up to you how you organize the scrollable GUI for the timeline (plenty of examples out there, starting with Flash/After Effectts/Blender/etc.) Feedback from your designer/animator is crucial I presume.

Pulling data from Flash could also be possible. If you'd like to parse the swf you can try Claus Wahlers' awesome [as3swf](https://github.com/claus/as3swf) library. Be sure to check some of his posts:

1. [SWF Timeline Reconstruction with as3swf](http://wahlers.com.br/claus/blog/timeline-reconstruction-with-as3swf/)
2. [Flash IDE Inspired Flex 4 Timeline Component](http://wahlers.com.br/claus/blog/flash-ide-inspired-flex-4-timeline-component/)

[image: as3swf Timeline in Flex4]

Another option would be to use jsfl (JavaScript scripting in the Flash IDE) and parse the tweens your designer/animator creates. It should be a matter of parsing a XML for the tween(be it old/[classic](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/motionXSD.html) or new/[motion](http://flashthusiast.com/2008/11/04/understanding-flash-cs4-motion-xml/)). If you go the JSFL route, you might also find the [xJSFL](http://www.xjsfl.com/) project useful.

Also, for inspiration on game/animation tools check out [Spriter](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/539087245/spriter)

Comment: Fantastic, I was indeed looking into as3swf but I wasn't able to find any useful documentation. Thank you very much. I think I'll be able to get something done today. My designer is hoping for something close to Adobe Premiere. I had searched for some information relating to Premiere project file types so perhaps he could simply import his Premiere into the game but I couldn't find anything helpful.

Comment: Out of curiousity, reccomendations for storing and traversing keyframes?

Comment: I'm glad you find the information useful. Most relevant as3swf classes should be in the [timeline](https://github.com/claus/as3swf/tree/master/src/com/codeazur/as3swf/timeline) package. I'm still confused by how a video project would fit into a level editor. Will this be a video based experience (more like a non linear narrative and less like a platformer for example) ? Not sure if Premiere can be scripted, but there is a [SDK](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/premiere.html) if you're comfy with C++.

Comment: If it's more like a non linear narrative video experience, can't the animator export separate sequences which you can control and transition with code ?

Comment: Yes and no. It's not definite that the game will be Flash or Flash only. But making the editor in AIR was a quick way for me develop since I'm not familiar with C# or other api tools. But I have made a lot progress and so far things a running quite smoothly. Thanks for you help.